# NC flag in htaccess causing Internal Server Error

Tags: .htaccess, case-insensitive

Whenever I add the [NC] flag in .htaccess, it causes an Internal Server Error.

This works:

`Redirect 301 /gabf http://www.mydomain.com/category/gabf`

but this doesn't:

`Redirect 301 /gabf http://www.mydomain.com/category/gabf [NC]`

How can I allow things like /gabf, /GABF, /Gabf, etc?

Comment: do you absolutely need to use the Redirect Directive?

Comment: Nope. I'm open to any solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^gabf/?$ http://www.domain.com/category/gabf [R=301,NC,L]
```

before:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Wordpress overwrite all RewriteRule to index.php. If you put that first, this "gabf" rule will be executed first and since it's the last rule it will stop.

R=301 = Redirect Permanent and NC = No Case (case insensitive)

Comment: It doesn't appear to be matching.. No redirect/rewrite is occurring.

Comment: did you remove: Redirect 301 /gabf http://www.mydomain.com/category/gabf? what else you have in your .htaccess? I assume your mod-rewrite is enable and you can allowoverride in the root folder